# Root Doesn't Have Sufficient Permission To Copy Directories/Files

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, VirtualBox5.1 (w. ext & guestadditions installed via synaptic), and I created a Ubuntu16.04 guest so that I could established a LAMP server Drupal dev environment.  While my LAMP is set-up with lesser pain than normal...  It now seems that my Root user on the guest machine has insufficient privileges to copy my drupal installations from the virtualbox shared folder into the guest ubuntu's public_html directory in the home directory.  I have started Nautilus using both sudo and gksudo and have had the same problem of some directories or files being unable to be copied....  any hints on how to solve this problem?
thx

Comment: Try it on the command-line, instead of Nautilus, and post the error message.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt... throw the GUI out...  I simply used

`sudo rsync -avrh  [source] [target]`

no more errors everything copied...

thanks